# UWP - How to select ListViewItem when a button inside it is clicked

Tags: uwp

I have a ListView, which ListViewItems have buttons, defined in ListView.ItemTemplate. How can I select a ListViewItem upon such button's Click event? I know how to make that in WPF, but can't figure for UWP, since UWP Styles don't support triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button clicked event add:

```
listView.SelectedItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
```

Comment: Hoped for a solution without code-behind, but atm only can make code behind. Yours or this:             var item = (Button)sender).DataContext;
            var container = (ListViewItem)ListviewTankVIEW.ContainerFromItem(item);
            container.IsSelected = true;

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a delegate command

The following example shows you how to accomplish this

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-bind-command-to-a-299f7759

but a simplier example is to use template 10 which has a delegate command already created for you.

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/MVVM#delegatecommand

To learn more on template 10 go to

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-template-10-16336

Comment: Sorry, my question might be not very clear, I need this: ListViewItems have buttons in one of their columns. Clicking such buttons raises Prism Command, but it either doesn't select ListViewItem, or (after changing some ListView properties) - it first fires a Command, then selects new ListViewItem. But I need ListViewItem to be selected first, then fire the Command